# Conditions for $E[Y_{n+1}\mid Y_n] = E[Y_{n+1}\mid\mathscr{F}_n]$

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Under what conditions, sufficient or necessary, does it hold that

$$E[Y_{n+1}\mid Y_n] = E[Y_{n+1}\mid\mathscr{F}_n]$$

if we are given a stochastic process $Y = (Y_n)_{n \geq 0}$ on a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, (\mathscr{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb{P})$ where $\mathscr{F}_n = \mathscr{F}_n^Y := \sigma(Y_0, Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$

?

I was under the impression that the equality held true *only* for Markov processes, but I guess there may be other conditions.

---

Markov property is:

$$E[f(Y_{t})\mid Y_s] = E[f(Y_{t})\mid\mathscr{F}_s]$$

$\forall 0 \le s \le t$ and $\forall f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ bounded and measurable.

So, if $Y_0, Y_1, \ldots, Y_n, \ldots$ is a Markov process, then we have

$$E[Y_{n+1}\mid Y_n] = E[Y_{n+1}\mid\mathscr{F}_n]$$

but what are other sufficient conditions? Some necessary conditions?

Comment: Suggestion: check the definitions (I know, the idea is crazy).

Comment: [Also asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306620/15941) on math.SE where it has received an answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Not a full answer.

Comment: I @Did. Markov property alternative formulation must hold for all bounded and measurable $f$ not just identity